# How to validate an input to certain numbers?

Tags: python

I was trying to find out how to validate the users input so that the their input can only be one of the following numbers: 1 2 or 3. My current code seems as if it doesn't recognize the variable which contains the 3 numbers:

**My Code**

```
options = "1", "2", "3"

    while True:
        option = input("\nEnter a Number [1][2][3]: ")
        if option == options:
            print ("Great")
        else:
            print ("Sorry, Invalid Input! Please Enter either [1] [2] [3]")
```

This code does not work as the `options` variable is not correctly written, as well the block of code under it. Any help would be great!

Comment: `options = ["1", "2", "3"]` and `option in options`, change this two things, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) instead, this is why we have them:

```
options = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Then, using the `in` operator that checks if a value is in the list, you can perform your membership tests:

```
while True:
    option = input("\nEnter a Number [1][2][3]: ")
    if option in options:
        print ("Great")
    else:
        print ("Sorry, Invalid Input! Please Enter either [1] [2] [3]")
```

Comment: You're welcome, Alex. Don't forget to mark one of the answers provided as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

use a set which has 0(1) lookup time complexity

```
options = set('1', '2', '3')
```

and then in your loop

```
if option in options:
    print ("Great")
    break # added break to end the while loop after a valid input
```

however if you need a value at each of those locations you can use a dictionary which also has 0(1) lookup time complexity but is a little more robust in terms of storage/memory

```
options = {
    '1': 'some value here',
    '2': 'some value here',
    '3': 'some value here'
}
```

Comment: @AhsanulHaque no, I don't think so. The `in` lookup on a dictionary is a ton faster than on a list. which is why I prefer it. And it doesn't have a lot more overhead anyways. In general its a better practice :)

Comment: Oh yes, didn't think in this way.

Comment: Great this is perfect, so creating a dictionary is the way, if you don't mind me asking what is the purpose of writing True after each number? Is there a purpose?

Comment: @AlexRyder the reason why I put true there is because the [**dictionary datatype**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) has two elements to it. a key and a value. the key is your number aka 1, 2, 3. and the value has to be something. I just put an arbitrary True there as the value. the `in` lookup looks directly at the keys which is why you want the numbers as the keys. does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, Great Explanation thanks, but just for clarification can True be replaced with anything other than True, if so some example would be?

Comment: @AlexRyder yea you def can do that.. an example could be `options = {'1': 'ONE'}` you can put any value in there. integers, strings, booleans anything :)

Comment: 1. List lookup is typically faster than dictionary lookup for a small number of elements. 2. If you don't have a real "value" but you are just interested in whether an element is there or not, use `set`, not `dict`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I appreciate the criticism. A few thoughts... this example the OP posted I don't think is the actual data (meaning there will be more than just three elements), which is why I proposed a dict. it is true that a list is faster for something like the first 4 elements. And the assumption was that the OP needs a value at that index/hash table. If you look at the comments thats exactly what he was looking for. I'll update to include a set as an alternative though

Comment: @JohnRuddell: just to clarify, I'm not the downvoter, I was just expressing a couple of possible weaknesses of your answer.